# Go through all the objects to which a macro can be assigned

Tags: vba, excel

As far as I know, in Excel we can assign macros to several kinds of objects: `shape`, `Form Control`, `ActiveX Control`...

I would like to write a VBA code to do the following, given an Excel file:

1. Go through all the existing objects which are eligible to be assigned to a macro
2. For each object found, print its name and the name of its macro (or ideally the body as well) if a macro is assigned.

I would like this to be exhaustive, could anyone help?

Comment: no way to do so, unfortunately...

Comment: Then there must be some ways to a closed goal. For instance, go through all the `shapes`, and list their assigned macros...

Comment: @KazJaw, your solution was good, why did you delete it?

Comment: I needed to improve it a bit...

Comment: This [link](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/control-loop.htm) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending @mehow answer for shapes located in `ActiveSheet` the following code will result with names of shape and it's macro name if one associated.

```
Sub getShapeMacro()

    'to secure for unexpected...
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim SHP As Shape
    For Each SHP In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        Debug.Print SHP.Name, SHP.OnAction
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Then why did you say "no way to do so"?

Comment: you can do it for each individual type of objects separately but you can't do it as described in point 1: 'Go through all the existing objects which are eligible to be assigned to a macro' at once. The answers here are 'close solution' to what you have expected.

Comment: OK, thank you... actually the objects in `ActiveSheet.Shapes` do include `Form Control` and `ActiveX Control`, though I don't know if they are exhaustive...

Comment: This won't work as not all Shape types have an OnAction method. If your book contains, for a simple example, a drop down list like from Data Validation this will error out. Also, while you can get the shape of an ActiveX object there is no OnAction that will tell you what code is assigned to it. You will have to add in guesses based on object type, Like it's  button to its code is `ObjectName_Click`. This also misses (and not sure if OA cares) all the actions and events by workbook or worksheet.

Comment: I am not interested in the actions and events by workbook or worksheet, whereas I do care `ObjectName_Click`, it seems that there is no automatic way to check if an object is eligible to have a `ObjectName_Click`...