# Check if OnAction is empty

Tags: vba, excel

In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19273601/702977), i use `SHP.OnAction` (where `Dim SHP As Shape`) to print the name of the macro which is assigned to a shape.

Now I would like to check if `SHP.OnAction` is empty, which means there is no macro assigned to this object.`SHP.OnAction = ""` does not work, it always return `false`. I have tried also ``SHP.OnAction = Empty`,`SHP.OnAction = Null`, they always return`false` too...

Could anyone tell me how to verify if it is empty?

**Edit1:** I use the following piece of code, to go through all the shapes in a workbook, and check if there is a shape to that a macro is assigned. I test it with some workbooks containing `Chart` or `Picture`, it seems that `sShpaes.OnAction <> ""` returns always `true`, even though the shape has no macro...

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim sShapes As Shape
existsAssignedShape = False

For Each ws In Worksheets
    For Each sShapes In ws.Shapes
        st = ws.Name & "     " & sShapes.Name & "     " & sShapes.OnAction
        Print #1, st
        Print #1, ""
        If (Not existsAssignedShape) And (sShpaes.OnAction <> "") Then
            existsAssignedShape = True
        End If
    Next sShapes
Next ws
```

Comment: I see... maybe it is related to the type of the shape... One shape which gives me the wrong result is a `Chart`, do you want to test it on your side?

Comment: This works as expected for me, even on Chart shapes.   `?Shp.OnAction = "" returns `True` if no macro is assigned, or `False` if a macro is assigned.

Comment: It would help to include the *exact* code you're currently using in your question: that's preferrable to just linking to a different question.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of all your modules and this kind of problem will be solved...  Meaning you have a pretty clear typo in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no macro has been assigned to an AutoShape, then the following will indicate **True**:

```
Sub hgfd()
    Dim s As Shape, t As String
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    t = CStr(s.OnAction)
    MsgBox t = ""
End Sub
```